# Icons not appearing through application but okay when opening directly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I am using bootstrap, but Icons will not work through VS 2013, if you load up icons.html directly it works fine and you can see the icons.  But through the web server the icons are not displayed

```
http://localhost:51501/icons.html
```

Here is the source

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54772190/bootstrap.zip

What is going on here?

Comment: Do you load your css files from different Domain? If yes, you may need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: Yes I've tried Access-Control-Allow-Origin, no effect.